# O que faz a window.location.reload?

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma dúvida sobre `window.location.reload(true)`.

Ele com o parâmetro *true*, realmente atualiza o site, baixando todos os arquivos de novo, sem usar o cache? Ou somente atualiza o site normalmente?

Comment: Na dúvida, você pode testar ;)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Renan!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação da [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Location/reload), esse parâmetro é chamado de `forceReload`.

> **Sintaxe:**
>   `window.location.reload(forcedReload);`
>
> `forcedReload`: É uma flag Boolean, que quando true, faz com que a página sempre seja
>   recarregada do servidor, se é false ou não for definido, o navegador
>   pode recarregar a página do cache.

Veja:

[Documentação sobre `location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Location/reload).

Comment: No caso o que vai estar true ou false no parâmetro vai ser essa forcedReload?

Comment: Pergunta boba a minha, é isso mesmo. Obrigado, Wallace! Quando der os 6min eu marco como certa!